# Can't block META_LEFT KeyEvent -- Is this an Android bug or is it me?

Tags: android

I have been researching this for days and have asked variations of this question.  I keep simplifying the question hoping to get an answer.  I have a bluetooth remote that sends a keyCode 117 which is META-LEFT and it causes the tablet to go to the music player.  This is not desirable as it exits my application.

As a test I have inserted this code:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e){
        return true;
}
```

This blocks all keys from my remote and from the tablet itself.  The tablet BackArrow is blocked, volume-up and volume-down on the remote and on the tablet are blocked (do nothing).  But the META_LEFT is popping up the music player.  It does this both on my Galzxy Tab-2 and Nexus-S.  Both are Android 4.0.4

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?  If the user presses this button, the app basically has crashed for all practical purposes.

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html), the "return true;" should prevent any action from taking place.  Is this an Android bug?  Am I missing something?

Comment: If there isn't a way to block this key, would there be a way to redefine what app is launched when the key is hit?  Maybe I could have it launch my app???